# Ruby: Cannot make UDP socket connection or send UDP packet to Android

Tags: android, ruby, sockets, udp

Good day,

I am making an Android app which sends UDP packets to Ruby server, which then forwards them to all subscribed android clients, including the original sender.

My server receives the packets, but is not able to send them or connect via UDP socket.

Server code snippet (Ruby, on Fedora 22):

```
SERVER_SEND_PORT = 4000
ANDROID_PORT = 7500

# Send socket
s_socket = UDPSocket.new
s_socket.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET,Socket::SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s_socket.bind(SERVER_IP, SERVER_SEND_PORT) 

# Receive socket
r_socket = UDPSocket.new
r_socket.setsockopt(Socket::SOL_SOCKET,Socket::SO_BROADCAST, 1)
r_socket.bind(SERVER_IP, RECEIVE_PORT)

$clientIPs = []
$clientPorts = []

def broadcast(data)             
  $clientIPs.each_with_index do |ip, index|
    puts "trying to send #{data}"
    s_socket.connect(ip, ANDROID_PORT)  # does not pass this step
    puts "connected"
    s_socket.send(data, 0)
    #s_socket.send(data, 0, ip, ANDROID_PORT)
    puts "sent: " + data;
  end
end

while true
  data, client = r_socket.recvfrom(256)
  puts "received: " + data
  Thread.new(client) do |clientAddr|
    if !$clientIPs.include? clientAddr[3]
      $clientIPs << clientAddr[3]
      $clientPorts << clientAddr[1]
    end

    broadcast(data)
  end
end
```

Client code snippet:

```
private static final int LISTENING_PORT = 7500;  

public void onStart() {

    /* Unrelated code + Sending socket */ 

    // Receiving Thread
    new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            // Create receiving socket at a given port
            try {
                rSocket = new DatagramSocket(LISTENING_PORT);
                rSocket.setBroadcast(true);
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("Trace", "Created receiving socket");

            while (true) {
                if (rSocket != null) {
                    // Receive data
                    byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                    try {
                        rSocket.receive(packet);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Got the packet!");
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

`netstat -u` does not show any UDP connections in the server.

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow, so any feedback/edits/tips are welcome.

Comment: I've solved this by rewriting my ruby code in Python. Therefore, it was definitely not the case that the server was blocking UDP sending for some reason.